# When login to Skype, a webpage is opened, listing files of C:\

Tags: windows, skype

I have downloaded the latest version of Skype for Windows from the official website and when I login with my existent user/password, a website is opened on Chrome, listing the directories of `C:\ProgramData\Skype\Apps\login`.

I use Windows Vista and here is a screenshot:

[image]

How I can solve this?

Comment: Do you have Facebook linked with Skype?

Comment: @ragnq: I tried with two accounts. I don't know in one of them but in mine I don't have it linked and fails in the same way. Thank you